# Lucene, Change Search on one file

Tags: search, lucene

Question about Lucene,

I have a file that I would like to index and search by different analyzers. My goal is to be able to change how I search.

In one case I would like to search exact phrase with punctuation IE. for "one,two" and only return exact matchings w/ punctuation.
I would also like to be able to search the exact phrase without punctuation. IE. for "one two." As in the StandardAnalyzer

Essentially I need to change the search functionality on one field.

How can I change the search on the same file. Ive tried using two analyzers (standard and whitespace) however this makes the indexing time very long.

My second thought is to use just a WhitespaceAnalyzer and when searching pass a query that further tokenizes each string if needed? However I am not sure which API has this if any do.

Also is there a good reading on how analyzers and tokens work and are implemented.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean you tried two analyzers? Duplicate the content to 2 seperate fields with different analyzers? That would be my suggestion.

Comment: Yeah, I created two file inputs to the same file and indexed with two two different fields. From more research it seems that I want to create my own custom analyzer/tokenizer. That itself needs more research.
Is there a good tutorial to start with that covers a variety of text based searching?